# Now that the player can become king, does MCA Reborn have an heir system and/or a family legacy system of sorts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

Like, if my dad was the player character and he married a villager that I edited to be a replica of my mom, and they had me and my two siblings, and then my dad became king but died during the course of the game, could my brother (the eldest of the three of us) then ascend to the throne, and then maybe the adult version of me could replace my dad as the player character?

Comment: Not knowing this mod, this question sounds very weird… :D